# database design for user rating

Tags: php, mysql

i'm building a user rating system to rate transactions between users. these are the tables i currently have.

```
user                
user_id  username   email       

rating              
rating_id   date    score   review  user_id

review              
review_id   user_id  rating_id
```

i'm not understanding how i would display the ratings for the users since i would be pulling the usernames from the same table.. do i create another table for reviewers or reviewed?

Comment: Quick search on your favorite search engine will tell you how to use aliases for tables and join them.

Answer (score 0):

Your user_id is the primary key for User table.
In your query, use a join on user_id to get the other fields from other tables.